# git branch -r is not displaying the same remotes as a colleagues computer

Tags: git, git-branch

I am thinking I have a git workflow problem here. I was cleaning up some remote branches and realized when helping out a colleague that both of our git references are "out-of-sync" some how.

For instance, if I open up git bash and type in the command "git branch -r" I get a list back like this:

- origin/branch1
- origin/branch2
- origin/branch4

now when I have my colleague do the same thing in their git bash prompt we get a list like back like this:

- origin/branch1
- origin/branch3
- origin/branch7

Notice that my colleague and I also have a case where we are seeing the same remote branch "branch1". This is what I would expect from running the bash command. What confuses me is the question "How come we have older and non existent branches still being returned."

How can I sync up both of our machines so that if we both run the "git branch -r" command, that we are returning the same information with regards to our remote repo.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sync your local machines with remote explicitly. The origin/some_branch that you both see are   based on your most recent git fetch. Git stores a version of remote on your local, which is then given the name origin/some_name. It is important to understand that you are not actually looking into a portal that views remote, but rather you are viewing remote and your local machine sees it. To update the snapshot of remote that your local has you run:

```
git fetch origin. # fetching the remote at origin
```

if you want you can run:

```
git fetch origin --prune
```

This will delete from your local origin/some_branch for any branch that is not tracked on your remote anymore. But make sure you know what you are doing when running destructive operations.

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html

Answer (score 0):

Try running `git fetch --prune` on both your computer and your colleague's one.

This will remove from your local repositories branches that doesn't exists on remote repository.

Output of `git branch -r` should be the same after this action.